# Pandoc for Linux Suse

Tags: linux, pandoc, suse

I don't know why I cannot ask a new question in the [pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss) Google group.

Then I ask my question here. One told me that Pandoc is not available for Linux Suse. Is it true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is available.  just go to http://software.opensuse.org/search and search for it (enter "pandoc" and hit return, then click on one of the results).  i use it all the time from opensuse.

[sorry; didn't realise you were asking about enterprise suse - my entire answer has been for opensuse]

Comment: Hello. Is it [Haskell Pandoc](http://software.opensuse.org/package/pandoc) ? I'm looking for [this pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)

Comment: yes, it's the same thing.  the program pandoc is written in the language haskell.

Comment: Hello andrew. Actually I'm not a Linux user but I use a Linux server at work. I have forwarded this link to my IT specialist colleague in order that he installs pandoc, but he claims that this is complicated. Is it really more complicated than for another Linux version ?

Comment: errr...  well, no it's not really complicated, but sometimes people say something is complicated when they mean that there are other reasons why they can't do it... it's generally not a good idea to argue with someone directly.  maybe offer to buy them some chocolate if they do it anyway...  good luck.

Comment: No, frankly, he is an excellent colleague ! Ok I will ask him more details about the problem.

Comment: Hello Andrew. My colleague claims that the texmath library is required for installing pandoc, and he doesn't find it for Suse.

Comment: if you install it via the link i gave, by adding a repository to suse, then dependencies are resolved automatically.

Comment: Sorry we don't understand. Should we download by clicking on "1 Click Install" in the link ? What do you mean by "adding a repository" ?

Comment: you can use the "1 click install" or you can manually start Yast and add a repository.  assuming you're looking at the opensuse 12.3 entry, "devel:languages:hask..." links to https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?project=devel%3Alanguages%3Ahaskell&package=pandoc and if you click on the "rspositories" tab that takes you to https://build.opensuse.org/package/repositories/devel:languages:haskell/pandoc which links to https://build.opensuse.org/package/binaries/devel:languages:haskell/pandoc?repository=openSUSE_12.3 which has a "go to download repository" link, and you can add *that* to yast.

Comment: yast, under "software", has a "software repositories" part.  if you add http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/haskell/openSUSE_12.3/ there, and refresh, then you can go to "software management" in yast and search for/select "pandoc" in the normal way.  but 1-click install does all that for you (i'm just explaining in detail in case you want to do it manually).

Comment: repositories are collections of programs that you can load into opensuse.  there's a standard one that is added when you install, but many more for specialized uses (like this one for haskell and pandoc).

Comment: Thank you very much. He has successfully installed Pandoc now !

Comment: Of course, Pandoc is a great tool. Unfortunately there's still a problem: we don't use opensuse but suse (version 11 SP2), and the latest version of Pandoc we have found is version 9, an old one :(

Comment: i am not surprised.  that is 4 years old and even evergreen support for 11.2 finishes this month.

Comment: What is 4 years old ? I think this is SUSE Linux Entreprise SP2 : https://www.suse.com/company/press/2012/2/suse-linux-enterprise-11-service-pack-2-released.html

Comment: oh, sorry - didn't realise the version numbers weren't in parallel.  opensuse 11.2 is 4 years old; i assumed that meant suse was too.